# Magento 2 Checkout How to identify that customer add new shipping address on checkout?

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, customer, shipping-address, customer-address

How to identify that customers add a new shipping address on checkout(if customers do not want that shipping address which showing on checkout page)?

After identifying the new address we need to update the customer address from the plugin.

We are using Plugin -

di.xml

```
 <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface">
        <plugin name="send_new_address_to_thirdparty" type="Companyname\Namespace\Plugin\OrderManagement"/>
    </type>
```

OrderManagement.php

```
public function beforePlace(
        OrderManagementInterface $subject,
        OrderInterface $order
    ): array {
        $quoteId = $order->getQuoteId();
        if ($quoteId) {
           
           json_encode($order->getShippingAddress()->getData()));
            
           json_encode($order->getBillingAddress()->getData()));

            die;
        }
        return $order;
    }
```

We are successfully getting data in our custom log but unable to identify is customer add new shipping address

Does anyone know how to identify if customers add a new shipping address?